# Nginx load balancing second server takes over if the first fails

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I've actually an Nginx configuration with two servers in load balancing and I would like to achieve this behavior:

1. the first server (the main one) should serve all the requests to everybody
2. if the main server fails for some reason, the second server should take over all the requests

Basically, the second server should act as a backup of the main one.
Of course I could use the two factors: max_fails=3  fail_timeout=15s on the first server BUT how to ensure that the usage of the main one is exclusive, avoiding the default round-robin behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `backup` attribute for the upstream

> backup
>
> marks the server as a backup server. It will be passed requests when the primary servers are unavailable.

```
upstream backend {
    server main.example.com       max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;

    server backup1.example.com  backup;
}
```

In this case backup will only be used when main is down